# Setting up mail smtp relay service to send and receive mail

Tags: smtp, imap, smtpclient, postmark, sendinblue

I have very limited knowledge about SMTP and IMAP/POP. SMTP --> sending message, IMAP--> Mainly for receiving messages.

I have a woocommerce website and i already did setup my email system to use SMTP relay using zoho. I believe zoho also provide mailbox services since I am able to communicate with my customer(both two and fro) using its email service. They have their app and i can receive and send mail from that app. Obviously, I have set up all the records including MX to send/receive the email to my zoho inbox.

No i want to move my email services to postmark or like sendinblue. All i can see the setting related to sending the mail but how/where will I receive the mail when user reply on that??
On the postmark website it says:
**Since Postmark is not a mailbox provider there's not the ability to generate mailboxes for receiving email using IMAP or POP3.**

**Question 1)** Does the SMTP relay server is actually a different physical machine from IMAP server for sending/receiving messages. I guess both are different but why are these companies not providing solutions like zoho. Pardon me if I did not understand the use case.

**Question 2)** What to do in this case ???. My case is simple. I send notifications to customers regarding their orders. If they want they can reply or enquire. I receive the email on my phone and I can reply on the same mail-chain like we have on Gmail.

**Question 3)**
Do i need to buy some another service along with these to receive and reply back on the email ??? Like from godaddy or somewhere else.

Comment: This site is for programming questions and tutorials are off-topic here. You are asking for several tutorials, none of them for programming.

Comment: I voted to close for one reason, but several other reasons are as valid... I hope your will find tutorials that suit you.

Comment: @arnt I don't think so my questions are invalid. For 1st my question is basically does both SMTP and IMAP server reside on the same server. The follow-up question on that is considered a bit off-topic though, i agree.

Comment: Whether to run two pieces of code in the same iron or different is ① not a programming question and ② a matter of opinion, so I think you'll find [little enthusiasm for that on SO.](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) I could argue both sides of that question, but prefer not to argue it at all. The lack of opinion and controversy is a big reason to keep answering questions, at least for me personally.